# Problem with \endhead in longtable: misalignment between the rows separated by \endhead

Tags: longtable, alignment

The code is the following:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
%\setTableNoteFont{\scriptsize}
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                       % Activate for rotated page geometry
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}                   % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{amsmath} % For table numbering based on Section
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false % <-- important
]{caption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=md]{caption}
%\usepackage{placeins} % for fixing table position
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for toprule,midrule, and bottomrule
%\usepackage{dirtytalk} % for quotes
\usepackage{lscape} % changes a page to a landscape
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,decorations.markings,,pgfplots.colorbrewer,shapes.arrows}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\usepgflibrary{curvilinear}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\tikzset{arrownode/.style={
    shape=single arrow,
    single arrow head extend=.75em,
    single arrow head indent=.25em,
    minimum width=3em,
    draw,
    }
}
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Use pdf, png, jpg, or eps§ with pdflatex; use eps in DVI mode
                                % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex        
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref} %Make this the last package imported
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} % Make footnotes to go to the buttom of a page
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen} % Makes sections colorful
\usepackage{pdfpages} % allows to load a pdf page into latex
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdftitle={Sharelatex Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}



\title{Experiment}
\author{Vahe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\pagebreak

\tableofcontents

\pagebreak

\section{Section A}

\subsection{Subsection A}

%\setlength\LTleft{-2in}
\setlength\LTright{2in}
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{l*{5}r}
\caption{Numbers}\\
%&\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Date}}}\\
\toprule
& May 2019 & Jun 2019 & Jul 2019 & Aug 2019 & Sep 2019\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{Continued}\\
\toprule
& May 2019 & Jun 2019 & Jul 2019 & Aug 2019 & Sep 2019\\
\midrule
\endhead
\makecell[l]{A} & 172.71 & 182.98 & 183.62 & 174.33 & 177.31 \\
\makecell[l]{B} & 18.29 & 18.45 & 18.35 & 18.38 & 23.36 \\
\makecell[l]{C} & 191.00 & 201.43 & 201.97 & 192.71 & 200.67 \\
\end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

Here is the resulting table.

[image]

As you can see there is misalignment. I can't understand theissue. If anyone knows how to deal with this, please help. Moreover \tableofcontents command only displays Content at the top of the second page nothing else. I will appreciate if you help me with this issue too. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you compile more than once? The table of contents should be filled when compiling twice and the issue about `longtable` should also be solved by compiling two or three times.

Comment: See also, the following quote from the `longtable` manual: "Various  parts  of  the  following  table  will not line  up  correctly  untilthis document has been run through LATEX several times.  This is a characteristic feature of this package, as described below."

Comment: Are longtable and booktabs compatible?  The longtable manual doesn't say.